# undefined reference to RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, gcc, rcpp

I am new to Rcpp. I am seeking help with the following problem. It seems that the RcppArmadillo does not work. Could someone give me some suggestions?
Many Thanks!

> g++ -m64 -I"D:/R/R-32~1.5/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/Rcpp/include" -I"D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppProgress/include" -I"D:/R/Rcode/Replicating/src" -I"D:/R/Rcode/Replicating/inst/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c test.cpp -o test.o
>
> In file included from D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppProgress/include/progress.hpp:13:0,
>                    from test.cpp:7:
>   D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppProgress/include/interruptable_progress_monitor.hpp:101:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp critical [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>
> D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppProgress/include/interruptable_progress_monitor.hpp:147:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp atomic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>
> D:/R/R-3.2.5/library/RcppProgress/include/interruptable_progress_monitor.hpp:153:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp critical [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>
> g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_7.dll tmp.def test.o -LD:/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LD:/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LD:/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64 -lR
>
> test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x61ee): 
>   undefined reference to `mvrnormArma(arma::Col, arma::Mat, int)'
>
> test.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x6d0e): undefined reference to `mvrnormArma(arma::Col, arma::Mat, int)'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Well you **definitely** need to include your code, but I'm guessing you did not put `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` in the source file.

Comment: @nrussell: It is a link error, not a compile error.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like a faily common and obvious error of having forgotten to update `src/Makevars`, and here `src/Makevars.win`, to contain

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

so that the *required* LAPACK and BLAS functionality is there.

For what it is worth, this also gets added *automagically* for you if you choose to start from `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` as is generally recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. Sorry for my stupid mistake

Comment: Should it be `src/Makevars` instead?